# Music for car Mercedes Benz C-class c320

Tags: linux, music, mp3, car

Today is my mother's birthday and I want to give her a gift. I downloaded her favorite 101 songs from Youtube, which are to be found in .mp3 format on my local machine. I want to create one or more CDs/DVDs, which could be played in her car. The model of the car is: Mercedes Benz C-class c320 and I am not really sure whether its DVD reader could play .mp3 format music or not, a conversion to tracks may be required, as I heard from one of my friends. Unfortunately, time is pressing me. I have to quickly find a method to make those CDs/DVDs. I am a Linux user, as I am using Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa, kernel x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-20-generic. I do not have that much time to search the web for this, so I am begging someone to give me the commands to run in terminal (or any other rapid solution), so that I can accomplish the mentioned task. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think `brasero` will convert mp3 (or other audio) to audio CD format and burn.    You must of course include this song - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qev-i9-VKlY

Comment: @TomaAlex Yay! Could you please mark the ivanivan's answer with a green tick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program `brasero` which should already be installed should be able to convert your MP3 to audio CD format and then burn.

You must of course include https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qev-i9-VKlY

And wish mom a happy birthday!